Trouble Locating Registry Key from Process monitor for Visual Studio Express
I have been using Process Monitor (Procmon) to track changes in the registry when I set up auto recovery and a few text editor settings in Visual Studio Express. However, I'm having trouble locating the specific registry key that is being modified. Despite seeing the activity in Procmon, I can't seem to find the exact registry key to verify or modify it manually.
The registry that is displayed in process monitor after making changes to the settings:

HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WDExpress\15.0_6c7fd93f\General

Auto Recovery:

\REGISTRY\A{b976085c-821e-d0bc-7ef3-9609c4ccc30d}\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\15.0_6c7fd93f\General\AutoRecover\AutoRecover
Save Interval

\REGISTRY\A{b976085c-821e-d0bc-7ef3-9609c4ccc30d}\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\15.0_6c7fd93f\General\AutoRecover\AutoRecover
Keep Interval



Text editor>Basic>snippet behavior:

\REGISTRY\A{b976085c-821e-d0bc-7ef3-9609c4ccc30d}\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\15.0_6c7fd93f\ApplicationPrivateSettings\TextEditor\VisualBasic\Specific\SnippetsBehavior


Text editor>C#>snippet behavior:

\REGISTRY\A{945d1672-c150-528f-a102-e67b94585dee}\Software\Microsoft\WDExpress\15.0_6c7fd93f\ApplicationPrivateSettings\TextEditor\CSharp\Specific\SnippetsBehavior



I am able to find "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WDExpress\15.0_6c7fd93f" , but not able to find the registry keys General, Autorecover, etc.
Hoping  someone here could provide some insight or solutions.
Thanks in advance

The settings can be changed by loading hive onto the local machine registry as given in the link below
Solution : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1691174/trouble-locating-registry-key-from-process-monitor?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1536211#newest-answer-comment
